# Reduce it array to an easier way to map

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, datatables

I'm developing an application and have added new items to my array: `type` and `description`.

```
array = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "description": "item1",
    "date": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "202001"
    },
    "item": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "I1"
    },
    "type": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "type1"
    },
    "price": 100
    },
    {
    "id": 2,
    "description": "item1",
    "date": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "202002"
    },
    "item": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "I1"
    },
    "type": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "type1"
    },
    "price": 200
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "description": "item1",
    "date": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "202002"
    },
    "item": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "I2"
    },
    "type": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "type2"
    },
    "price": 300
  },
]
```

I previously did this to reduce it down to an easier way to map it:

```
 items = array.reduce((acc, e) => {
    if (!acc[e["item"]["name"]]) {
      acc[e["item"]["name"]] = {
        [e["date"]["name"]]: e["price"]
      }
    } else {
      acc[e["item"]["name"]][e["date"]["name"]] = e["price"]
    }
    return acc
  }, {})
```

To show the data before I did

```
const dates = [...new Set(Object.keys(items_dicc).map(i => Object.keys(items_dicc[i])).flat())]

{
  Object.keys(items_dicc).map((item) => {
    return (
      <tr>
       <td>{item}</td>
       {dates.map((date) => <td>{items_dicc[item][date] || ''}</td>)}
      </tr>
    )
  })
}
```

I need to add the `description` element and `type.name` to the above. For example for `description`:

```
description: e["description"]
```

To display the elements as in the table:

| ITEM | DESCRIPTION | TYPE | 202001 | 202002 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| I1 | item1 | type1 | 100 | 200 |
| I2 | item3 | type2 | - | 300 |

How do I add and show?

**EDIT**: `console.log(items_dicc[item])`

```
{202001: 100, 202002: 200, description: "item1", type: "type1"}
202001: 100
202002: 200
description: "item1"
type: "type1"
__proto__: Object

{202002: 300, description: "item3", type: "type2"}
202002: 300
description: "item3"
type: "type2"
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to achieve. Could you include an example of how you want `items` to look in your question?

Comment: I added a table so you can visualize it. Thank!

Comment: I have been seeing your question regarding these type of tables from yesterday. You have posted several questions with similar things. I suggest you to read some article and understand how JS array methods works instead of asking incremental questions in SO. Asking in SO might solve your problems for now, but in the long run you will suffer as you don't seem to have a grip on how these things works.

Comment: how do you get item1 -> 202002 = 200?

Comment: @D. Seah Corrected, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the description and type attribute inside the reduce method like this,

```js
array = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "description": "item1",
    "date": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "202001"
    },
    "item": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "I1"
    },
    "type": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "type1"
    },
    "price": 100
    },
    {
    "id": 2,
    "description": "item2",
    "date": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "202002"
    },
    "item": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "I1"
    },
    "type": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "type1"
    },
    "price": 200
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "description": "item3",
    "date": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "202002"
    },
    "item": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "I2"
    },
    "type": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "type2"
    },
    "price": 300
  },
]


items = array.reduce((acc, e) => {
    if (!acc[e["item"]["name"]]) {
      acc[e["item"]["name"]] = {
        [e["date"]["name"]]: e["price"],
        'description': e['description'],
        'type': e.type?.name,
      }
    } else {
      acc[e["item"]["name"]][e["date"]["name"]] = e["price"]
    }
    return acc
  }, {})

console.log(items);
```

To add the  for description and name in the table,

```
const dates = [...new Set(Object.keys(items_dicc).map(i => Object.keys(items_dicc[i])).flat())]

{
  Object.keys(items_dicc).map((item) => {
    return (
      <tr>
       <td>{item}</td>
       <td>{items_dicc[item]?.description}</td>
       <td>{items_dicc[item]?.type}</td>
       {dates.map((date) => <td>{items_dicc[item][date] || ''}</td>)}
      </tr>
    )
  })
}
```

**I have been seeing your question regarding these type of tables from yesterday. You have posted several questions with similar things. I suggest you to read some article and understand how JS [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) methods works instead of asking incremental questions in SO.
Asking in SO might solve your problems for now, but in the long run you will suffer as you don't seem to have a grip on how these things works.**

Comment: Thank you! I'm learning, and I'm making the array more complex to cover all the possibilities. I have tried that not everything is in the same question to maintain an order. Excuse me.

Comment: One more question, I have tried to display the data in the table without success, do you show me how to do it? Thank you!

Comment: Without that part of the code it is hard for us to tell you how to do it.

Comment: Ok, I add it in the question

Comment: I added the code that I use to generate the table, now I need to display each of the columns well.

Comment: It doesn't work ('description' is not defined), you can check it. Thank you!

Comment: Can you console.log items_dicc[item] ?

Comment: I added the console output to the question

Comment: It worked to fetch the `description` and `type` columns, but `{dates.map((date) => <td>{items_dicc[item][date] || ''}</td>)}` still shows all the data: `description`, `type` and and the elements for each period

Comment: The same with `{dates.map(date => <th>{date}</th>)}` should only bring the names of the dates

Answer (score 1):

you can simplify your solution like this.

```js
const array = [{
    "id": 1,
    "description": "item1",
    "date": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "202001"
    },
    "item": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "I1"
    },
    "type": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "type1"
    },
    "price": 100
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "description": "item2",
    "date": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "202002"
    },
    "item": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "I1"
    },
    "type": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "type1"
    },
    "price": 200
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "description": "item3",
    "date": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "202002"
    },
    "item": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "I2"
    },
    "type": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "type2"
    },
    "price": 300
  }
]

const result = array.map(item => {
    return Object.keys(item).reduce((a, c) => {
        if (c === "date") {
            a[item[c].name] = item.price; 
        } else if (c !== "price" && c !== "id") {
            a[c] = (typeof item[c] === "object") ? item[c].name : item[c];
        }
        return a;
    }, {})
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Great, it's another great way to do it. How nice it is to learn! Thanks for your help!

Comment: you are welcome. remember that your code has to be simple otherwise, it is hard to maintain.